# How to join two list on basis one attribute in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have two list master and vehicleFareData.

VehicleFareData has two field **id** and **vehicleFare**. Master has multiple field including **id** ,**vehicleFare**.

Now i want to replace the field **vehicleFare** in master with the **vehicleFare** in vehicleFareData list where the **id** of master is equal to **id** of VehicleFareData

What is the best way to achieve this in Kotlin

```
fun getMasWithVehicleFare(fareCalculation: FareCalculation, mas: ArrayList<Driver_Available>): ArrayList<Driver_Available> {
    for (vehicleData in fareCalculation.vehiclesPricingData) {
        mas.find { it.mid == vehicleData.driverID }!!.fare = vehicleData.fare
    }
        return mas
    }
```

is this the correct way?

Comment: add some code of what you had tried so far

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite good though it may fail if you don't find an element from `vehicleData` in `mas`
But you can improve its CPU time consumption for searching objects by using a `Map` instead of `ArrayList`
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/index.html

> A collection that holds pairs of objects (keys and values) and supports efficiently retrieving the value corresponding to each key

I think that your problem is more a problem of using the good collection type rather than writing the good algorithmic code which is quite okay from what I read you wrote